# Create a Binary Header

Tags: swift, header, binary, byte, bit

I have to encode on 16 bits two information : Id and length.

I will explain in more detail.

Exemple :

```
let id: UInt16 = 4 // 0000 0000 0000 0100
let length: UInt8 = 2 // 0000 0010
```

I would like to encode on this form.

```
(Id=0000 0000 0001 00)(Length=10) // 0000 0000 0001 0010
```

I did a bit shift

```
let header: UInt16 = id << 2 // 0000 0000 0001 0000
```

So now I'm blocked to add the two bits of the length.

Thanks for reading

Comment: In `header`, how many bits do you want to give to `id` and how many for `length`? What should `header be` if say `id = 0b1111_1111_1111_1111` and `length = 0b1010_1010` ?

Comment: 14 bits for id and 2 bits for length // (Id 14bits =0000 0000 0001 00)(length 2 bits =10) The id will never go over 14bits and the length 2 bits

Comment: How about `let header: UInt16 = (id << 2) + UInt16(length & UInt8(0b11))`?

Comment: Thanks it works ! but wha't means "0b11" ?

Comment: That's in binary. Have a look [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID323).

Comment: If you are SURE length will never be more than 3 (2 bits), then you can simply write let header: UInt16 = (id << 2) + UInt16(length) ; combining with & Uint(0b11) guarantees that even if length is more than or equal to 4, you keep just the 2 lowest bits and not write over the 14 leading bits.

Comment: And if everything is declared as UInt16, simply write let header = id << 2 + length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that `id` is never going to exceed `0b0011_1111_1111_1111` and that `length` is at most `0b0000_0011` then you can encode the header this way :

```
let header: UInt16 = (id << 2) + UInt16(length)
```

And you can check the result this way :

```
let leadingZeros = String(repeating: "0", count: header.leadingZeroBitCount)
print(leadingZeros + String(header, radix: 2))  //0000000000010010
```